# Vue computed is not working properly and is always false

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I was just trying to add a class if the number is greater than 0 and add a other class if it is less than 0.

Here is my code:

```js
var prices = new Vue({
  el: "#prices",
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue!",
    currencies: [],
  },
  computed: {
    color() {
      return this.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency > 0 ? "inc" : "dec";
    }
  },
  // Getting the Data DO NOT TOUCH! :)
  mounted: function() {
    axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=1h%2C%2024h%2C7d")
      .then(response => {
        this.currencies = response.data;
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<table id="prices">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="currency, index in currencies">
      <td v-html="index + 1"></td>
      <td :class="color">{{currency.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency.toFixed(2)}}%</td>
      <td :class="color">{{currency.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}}%</td>
      <td :class="color">{{currency.price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency.toFixed(2)}}%</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I am doing it with computed: color(). Everything is working but it always adds the class "dec" to the tabledata, even though it is greater than 0.

Please end my suffering with helping me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean `this.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency` ?

In my opinion, you should make computed functions like this.

```
<td :class="color(currency.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency)"></td>

methods() {
   color (currency) {
      return currency > 0 ? "inc" : "dec";
   }  
}
```

Comment: Alright. I had to write `methods` instead of `computed`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't have this param in your data `this.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency`

You need to use something like this

```
methods: {
    color(price) {
      return price > 0 ? "inc" : "dec";
    }
  }
```

and send price from template

Answer (score 1):

In your computed function you are referencing the variable  `this.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency`, but this variable is neither defined in the data nor is it obtained through props.
So the default value of that will be `undefined`.

Looking at the HTML part I'm assuming that `price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency` is part of the object obtained in the response list data from the API.

So what you can do is to compute the data in the `then` part of the API call.

```js
mounted: function() {
    axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=1h%2C%2024h%2C7d")
      .then(response => {
        this.currencies = response.data;
        this.currencies.forEach(currency => {
          currency['color'] = currency.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency > 0 ? "inc" : "dec";
        })
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

and then in html use it like so

```html
<td :class="currency.color">{{currency.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency.toFixed(2)}}%</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `color` property is defined on the component itself and not on each currency object. All the generated `td`s will refer to the same `color` property which is calculated using the property `price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency` on the component which is `undefined` because the component doesn't have one.

Either add the `color` property to the currency objects when they're fetched:

```
  .then(response => {
    response.data.forEach(item =>
      item.color = item.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency > 0 ? "inc" : "dec"
    );
    this.currencies = response.data;
  })
```

Or, better yet, compute the class in the template, add it to `tr` so you don't have to repeat it for each of the child `td`s:

```
<tr v-for="currency, index in currencies" :class='[ currency.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency > 0 ? "inc" : "dec" ]'>
```

**demo:**

```js
var prices = new Vue({
  el: "#prices",
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue!",
    currencies: [],
  },
  computed: {
    color() {
      return this.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency > 0 ? "inc" : "dec";
    }
  },
  // Getting the Data DO NOT TOUCH! :)
  mounted: function() {
    axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=eur&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=1h%2C%2024h%2C7d")
      .then(response => {
        this.currencies = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
})
```

```css
.dec {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
}

.inc {
  background-color:#aaffaa;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<table id="prices">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="currency, index in currencies" :class='[ currency.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency > 0 ? "inc" : "dec" ]'>
      <td v-html="index + 1"></td>
      <td>{{currency.price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency.toFixed(2)}}%</td>
      <td>{{currency.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}}%</td>
      <td>{{currency.price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency.toFixed(2)}}%</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```